# properly escape ' in bash sql query?

Tags: sql, bash

i am writing a bash script to collect data from a postgresql remote db.
one command looks like this

```
count_test=$(ssh ha@110.34.123.10 "psql -U user -d db_name -h localhost -c 'select count(*) from acts where created_date::date = date '2020-08-17'';")
```

The problem is how to escape ' or correctly change the query?

Above format thows an error of syntax error at 2020...

The sql query is

```
select count(*) from acts where created_date::date = date '2020-08-17'
```

I have tried escaping with \ but that also throws error. The prob is sigle quotes needed to surround date variable.

Comment: Putting the query into a file and using `-f query.sql` is usually a much easier alternative. Or use a "HERE doc".

Comment: how can i execute it over ssh then, also would it require sqlplus??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For local run it's

```
psql -U user -d db_name -h localhost -c "select count(*) from acts where created_date::date = date '2020-08-17' "
```

So, over ssh it should be:

```
ssh user@host psql -U user -d db_name -h localhost -c " \"select count(*) from acts where created_date::date = date '2020-08-17' \" "
```